# JQuery error in a Firefox extension

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-plugins, firefox-addon

```js
var $j;
$j = jQuery.noConflict();    
$j(<button id="find" label="AdWords OK"/>).append("#:ne");
```

I get the error  "i.createDocumentFragment is not a function" when I run it in a Firefox extension.

Comment: missing quotes i think $j('<button id="find" label="AdWords OK"/>')

Comment: @Huangism: Firefox interprets this string (without quotes) as an XML literal - see E4X. But at least jQuery 1.7.1 errors out with "Cannot wrap XML objects".

Comment: In what context are you running this code? Add-on SDK module? Content script? Browser window overlay?

Answer (score 1):

```
$j('<button id="find" label="AdWords OK"/>').append("#:ne");
```

need quotes no?

Edit

Oh adding it after the #ne, then

```
$j('#ne').after('<button id="find" label="AdWords OK"/>');
```

Comment: doesn't matter, but if you use single you don't need to escape the double quotes you already have. The quotes is the most basic part of jquery, you don't need quotes if it is a variable but since you are targeting html, then you need quotes